# how to add Clear system Files in appium

Tags: appium

i have to perform login activity in android application using appium java. my application is opening but login is not happening and getting below error in in appium server. 
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.

Actual Result: Android application is opening but login activity not performed and giving below error:
Appium server is giving error like '[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.'
Expected Result: Appium server should not get error and Login activity should also perform, once application is opened

```
package Automation;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class AppiumTest2 {
AppiumDriver driver;

public  void setup() throws Exception  {

    DesiredCapabilities Capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    Capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "codeblaze");
    Capabilities.setCapability("platforVersion", "7.0");
    Capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Adnroid");
    Capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "package name");
    Capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "activity name");
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), Capabilities);


}

public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}


public void LogInWithInvalidEmail() {

    WebElement emailTextField = (new WebDriverWait(driver,60)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("etusername")));
    emailTextField.sendKeys("Invalid Email");

    WebElement passwordTextField = driver.findElement(By.id("etpassword"));
    passwordTextField.sendKeys("Random Password");

    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("lllogin"));
    loginButton.click();

}
}
```

Appium server is giving error like '[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.'
Expected Result: Appium server should not get error and Login activity should also perform, once application is opened

Comment: Define your appiumDriver as static. Also add the appium server log. You must look few line above in your appium server log

Answer (score 0):

1. It should be [as simple as](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/remote/MobileCapabilityType.html#CLEAR_SYSTEM_FILES):

   Capabilities.setCapability(io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType.CLEAR_SYSTEM_FILES, true);
2. another issue might be connected with the typo in the [`platformName` capability](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.html#PLATFORM_NAME) which should be `Android`, not `Adnroid`
3. It's better to stick to [Page Object Model](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) design pattern in Selenium and/or Appium tests, it will allow you to split UI representation from the test logic.
4. If above hints will not help - consider restarting the device/simulator.

More information: [App was not copied, so not deleting](https://discuss.appium.io/t/app-was-not-copied-so-not-deleting/15293)

Comment: i have tried same code Capabilities.setCapability(io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType.CLEAR_SYSTEM_FILES, true);                 and also change platformName to Android but still getting same error in appium server.